# How to use OKLab color space?

Tags: c++, color-space, lab-color-space

I try to use [Oklab color space](https://bottosson.github.io/posts/oklab/) with [original cpp header file](https://bottosson.github.io/misc/ok_color.h).
My code :

```cpp
#include <cstdlib> // malloc
#include <cfloat>
#include <cmath> // -lm
#include <cstdio> // printf
#include "ok_color.h" //  ok_color.h : Oklab color space. A perceptual color space for image processing by 2021 Björn Ottosson

using namespace ok_color;

int main(void){

    struct Lab c;
    c.L = 100.0f;
    c.a = 0.0f;
    c.b = 0.0f;
    
    
    
    struct RGB rgb;
    rgb =  oklab_to_linear_srgb(c); 
    
    //
    printf("LAB : L = %.16f a = %.16f b = %.16f\n", c.L, c.a, c.b);
    printf("RGB : r = %.16f g = %.16f b = %.16f\n", rgb.r, rgb.g, rgb.b);
    return 0; 
}
```

I compile it and run

```
 g++ o.cpp -Wall -lm
./a.out
```

The result is :

```
LAB : L = 100.0000000000000000 a = 0.0000000000000000 b = 0.0000000000000000
RGB : r = 1000000.1875000000000000 g = 1000000.1250000000000000 b = 999999.93750
```

It is different then expected ( checked with [Lch and Lab colour and gradient picker](https://davidjohnstone.net/lch-lab-colour-gradient-picker) ) : rgb(255,255,255)

How should I do it ?

Comment: If you were attempting to convert "white" to RGB, I believe that input should be `1.0`, `0.0`, `0.0`. Neither input nor output seem to give special meaning to "100.0" or "255".

Comment: @DrewDormann "The lightness value, L*, also referred to as "Lstar," defines black at 0 and white at 100. "

Comment: @DrewDormann I think you are correct. OkLab is quite different from CIELAB and Lstar appears to be white when it's = 1.  This has little to do with CIELAB and probably should be called something entirely different. Attempts to create perceptually even steps in some colorspace have been failures. In large part because color perception is not only dependent on the environment something is viewed in but also just the knowledge of what one is looking at is. Like a monitor v a table top.  It's crazy how the brain alters one's sense of color.

Comment: Looks like OkLab is completely different from CIELab.  White in OkLab is (1,0,0), not (100,0,0) Further it looks like the conversion to sRGB is to linear space and it should be to the modified gamma encoding of sRGB. But that's another issue. I removed my answer because it doesn't pertain to OkLab which is radically different from CIELab. Just change `c.L=1`

Comment: For what it's worth, the page linked in the question only demonstrates L values in the range `0.0` to `1.0`.